# Weird value at the end of a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

the function is called here

printf("copy %s\n", string_dupe(s1));

and the function is

```
char* string_dupe(char *s){
    char* new_s;
    new_s = malloc(8 * sizeof(s));
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < size_of(s); i++){
        new_s[i] = s[i];
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return new_s;
}
```

So i've created the NULL byte or i at least think i have. But whenever i run this is keeps getting random values on the end of the input string. i put statements around it checking the ith value and it appears to be a null byte. i also check the next i + 1 element and it is never the same as the value that appears, can anyone help me out?

example input 
s[] = "beetles"

ouput - beetles?

Comment: Your memory allocation does not take account of the length of the string it is to duplicate. I just allocates 8 bytes. And what is `size_of`?

Comment: Size_of gets the length of the string and what do you mean? I also tried larger multiplications in the malloc function 30 * sizeof(*s) and such

Comment: `8 * sizeof(*s)` is `8 * 1` is `8`.

Comment: Please show some example input. Better still, please also post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Are we just going to ignore the leak?

Comment: Use `strlen(s)` instead of `sizeof`

Comment: sorry updated the information

Comment: You have just altered the code. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Actual code, not *something like* your code.

Comment: Your code overwrites the input instead of terminating the output. `s[i] = '\0';` while yout returning `new_s`.

Comment: Random bytes when you look at it in the debugger or when you actually try and use or print the data?  It's perfectly normal to have random bytes after the null if you did not set all of the memory to zero, but they don't matter if you're manipulating the data as a null terminated string.  Perhaps you could post a complete example. I'm curious what `size_of` does.

Comment: @Sniper `sizeof(*s)` is okay, but the multipliert shouldn't be a const literal `8`.

Comment: `s[i] = '\0';` --> `new_s[i] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(s)` will return the size of the pointer which is 4 or 8 byte. And `sizeof(*s)` will return size of char (because `s` is `char*`) which is 1 byte. To get the length of the string you have to iterate over it until you reach `\0` or use `strlen`.

```
char* string_dupe(char *s){
    unsigned int len = 0;
    while (s[len] != '\0') ++len;                // conpute length of string
    char* new_s = (char*) malloc(len + 1);       // one extra byte for '\0'
    unsigned int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        new_s[i] = s[i];
    }
    new_s[i] = '\0';                             // Append '\0' to new_s not s
    return new_s;
}
```

Comment: You should specifically mention the major bug spotted by @harper instead of just correcting it.

Comment: @WeatherVane sure

Comment: thanks man, i guess i didnt have a great understanding of malloc, was thinking it assigned bits. and i cant believe i missed the null byte assignment. One thing i am confused about is the purpose of the (char*) before the malloc statement in your code

Comment: That is type casting the return value of malloc to `char*` . Since malloc returns `void*`. It may work without the casting but compiler may throw a warning. e.g.  g++ throws an error but gcc does not.

Answer (score 2):

1. use `strlen(s)` to compute the length of the string.
2. you are suppose to terminate string pointed by `new_s` with `'\0'` not `s`.

   ```
   char* string_dupe(char *s)
   {
       char* new_s;
       size_t len = strlen(s);

       new_s = malloc(len+1);
       if (new_s != NULL)
           strcpy(new_s,s);
       return new_s;
   }
   ```